# How to call method that compares two strings from another class (package)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods, call, package

I have 2 classes in java folder in intellij (i mean two different files):

**Main.class** and
**Fields.class**

In **Fields.class** i just want to save all fields that i test on my App (Name, Surname, Tel etc). For example:

```
String a1 = "Tom";
String b1 = "James";
```

In **Main.class** i write code and trying to call some methods. For example i want to write method that сompares 2 strings from **Fields.class**. My result here:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String var1;
    String var2;

    class equalsM {
          void equalsMethod(String a1, String b2) {
            if (a1.equals(b1)) System.out.println("OK");
            else System.out.println("Bad");
        }
    }
```

I want to write a method once and call this method everytime i need it..

My problem: i don know how i can call method **equalsMethod** in my **Main.class** and compare those strings from **Fields.class**

I'm reading Herbert Schildt's book and still don't understand some basics...

Comment: Your equalsMethod method is not a method of the main class. It's a method of a local inner class equalsM defined inside the main method of the Main class. Define the method directly in the Main class. Make it static since it's a pure utility method, not needing access to the state of any instance of Main. Make it public, too, so it's visible from anywhere, and call it from anywhere using Main.equalsM(...). This is basic stuff that is covered by any introductory Java book, or the Java tutorial. Read that before asking questions. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use data from Fields.java in Main.java.This does not solve my problem

Comment: If it doesn't solve the problem, then it means you did something wrong. But you didn't post your attempt, so it's impossible to say what. You can't possibly have read and digested the Java tutorial I linked to in such a short time, either. So take a step back, and read. Carefully.

Answer (score 0):

To call a method depends on its status. There are two kind of methods: instance and class methods. Instance method can be called only with an instance, while class methods can be called on the class (instanciated or not).

First.

When you define:

```
class equalsM {
    void equalsMethod(String a1, String b2) {
        if (a1.equals(b1)) System.out.println("OK");
        else System.out.println("Bad");
    }
}
```

You define a class with an instance method `equalsMethod`. To call it you need to instanciate the class:

```
equalsM i = new equalsM();
i.equalsMethod("foo","bar");
```

It is probably not what you expect because instanciating such a class for something which behave like a function is not necssary. You probably need a static method, like:

```
class equalsM {
    static void equalsMethod(String a1, String b2) {
        if (a1.equals(b1)) System.out.println("OK");
        else System.out.println("Bad");
    }
}
```

in which case call it could simply be:

```
equalsM.equalsMethod("foo","bar");
```

Second.

Don't use inner class for such a need, define your `equalsM` class outside and use it as suggested.

Third.

Spell your classes like it is suggested in many conventions: `EqualsM` (first letter uppercase).

As commented, your design is very bad, I suggest you to read about basic OOP.

Comment: When i write:  static void equalsMethod(String a1, String b1) {
            if (a1.equals(b1)) System.out.println("OK");
            else System.out.println("Bad");
        } i'm getting error. Can not resolve symbol a1, b1

Comment: Thanks. But how can i user data from Fields.java in my Main.java project? How can i call my method and use data from Fields.java ? Its impossible?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a need to define inner class then you can use static method to execute your code or you can use above examples suggested by others.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fields field = new Fields();

        String var1 = field.a1;
        String var2 = field.b1;
        equalsMethod(var1,var2);
    }

    private static void equalsMethod(String var1, String var2) {
        if (var1.equals(var2)) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Bad");
        }   
    }
}
```